# ComboBox Binding in WPF

Tags: wpf, data-binding, combobox

I am not able to set the selected value of a combobox.

this is how i am doing.

```
ComboBox x:Name="cmbProjectStatus" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemListCollection}" 
         DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
         SelectedValuePath="ID" 
         SelectedValue="{Binding Path=ItemList.ID}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ItemList}" 
         HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

I am using MVVM pattern in my project

Please Help...

Answer (score 4):

but wait, your selected value is defined because you set selecteditem and selectedvaluepath ;)you don't have to set selectedvalue, and
**EDIT**
ItemList seted as SelectedItem exists in ItemListCollection

This should work

```
   ComboBox x:Name="cmbProjectStatus" ItemsSource="{Binding ItemListCollection}" 
             DisplayMemberPath="Name" 
             SelectedValuePath="ID"
             SelectedItem="{Binding Path=ItemList}" 
             HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
```

if you want to get it worked in your case just override Equals method in your Item class like this

```
public class Item
    {
        ...
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            Item i = (Item)obj;
            if (i.ID == this.ID)
                return true;
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Comment: What if you cannot override Equals because it's a class you cannot modifiy? (third party). Is there any way to deal with this without a wrapper class?

Comment: I would create new class ex. ItemViewModel, which contains Item, and have Equals override there, after use this as source to combobox

Comment: It's what I ended up doing! I thought there was another way without wrapping it up or overriding Equals.